# Calculating total and sales tax

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm new to Python and need help with my homework.

Write a program that ask for the price of each item, then displays the subtotal of the sale, tax, and total.

```py
item1 = float(input("Enter Price of item 1 = $"))
item2 = float(input("Enter Price of item 2 = $"))
item3 = float(input("Enter Price of item 3 = $"))
item4 = float(input("Enter Price of item 4 = $"))
item5 = float(input("Enter Price of item 5 = $"))
subTotal = ("item1 + item2 + item3 + item4 +item5")
tax = 0.07 * subTotal
total = subTotal + tax
```

I get this error message:

```
tax = 0.07 * subTotal
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'
```

Comment: You've stated the assignment description and your attempt, but not what you need help with.

Comment: Remove all quotes from this line: `subTotal = ...`.

Comment: What i need help with is the error message that im getting    tax = 0.07 * subTotal
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting that error because you are trying to multiple 0.07 by a String i.e. non-int type. Remove the quotations from subTotal line.

```
item1 = float(input("Enter Price of item 1 = $"))
item2 = float(input("Enter Price of item 2 = $"))
item3 = float(input("Enter Price of item 3 = $"))
item4 = float(input("Enter Price of item 4 = $"))
item5 = float(input("Enter Price of item 5 = $"))
subTotal = (item1 + item2 + item3 + item4 +item5)
tax = 0.07 * subTotal
total = subTotal + tax
```